# Crash : Back button of UINavigationController and threads

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a thread (an asynchronous operation) which it downloads some datas from a server, and when the download is end, this thread calls a method. But if the user press the back button of the navigation controller before the download is ended, then I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) fatal error.

I tried many things but I can't handle this crash.

How can I handle errors when a user press the back button of a navigation controller before an asynchronous operation is ended ?

I use Objective-C and Dropbox API, and the method I use is

```
loadThumbnail:ofSize:intoPath of the class DBRestClient.
```

When I press the back button, I get informations with the help of zombie objects and Profile Inspector. Thanks to them I can see the last call before crash is :

```
[DBRequest connectionDidFinishLoading:]
```

But this call is done after the release of all of my objects in the dismissed view controller.

Comment: your UI operations must run in main thread and you are trying to update UI from background app. So when background thread is trying to update the UI your views is already popup from the navigation and does not exists. Just check if your user is still on the same UI before updating.

Comment: No, I just do the download of datas in an asynchronous task that it calls a method in my class, and after, in this method, I update UI in the main thread.

Comment: so you are calling this method from your async task? which keeps it in the same async thread. If user clicks the back button your class is still in existence?

Comment: Yes, but I used a dispatch_async() with dispatch_get_main_queue() parameter.

No my class isn't still in existence, and that's my problem.

Comment: I would suggest instead of directly calling your class method, post a local notification from your async thread and let your UI class work on it if it receives the notification.

Comment: are you using Swift or Obj-C? If you're using Swift you can use guard statement to check if your class is nil and then just return without calling your method.

Comment: Edit the question with ur code snippet

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with more informations

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the running request in the dealloc. `DBRequest` has a `cancel` method, `DBRestClient` has a `cancelAllRequests` method.

Also set all relevant delegates to nil.

`connectionDidFinishLoading:` is a method of the protocol `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`. Here's it's called on an object, that's no longer there, thus the crash.